# Addthis popup not always showing

Tags: popup, mailchimp, addthis

i am developing a custom website, i added the AddThis popup, linked it to Mailchimp and set the audience to "All visitors", but the popup is showning only on the first entry to the website. this is the website link imadeddine.co/Arvin

i appreciate if you could help with this.

Imad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the Support and they told me that it is build like this, the popup will appear again after 30 days or after you clear your browser cache.

i hope this will help someone